Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '*databasename*'. -Kubernetes with SQL Server and .NET8
I have a service named PlatformService written in .NET 8, trying to run it in a Kubernetes, that connects with SQL Server. I get this error in the PlatformService Kubernetes deployment:
 2024-08-13 12:41:14 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
    2024-08-13 12:41:14       An error occurred using the connection to database 'platformsdb' on server 'mssql-clusterip-srv,1433'.
    2024-08-13 12:41:14 info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10404]
    2024-08-13 12:41:14       A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 0ms.
    2024-08-13 12:41:14       Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "platformsdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
    2024-08-13 12:41:14       Login failed for user 'sa'.
    2024-08-13 12:41:14          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    2024-08-13 12:41:14          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
    2024-08-13 12:41:14          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
    2024-08-13 12:41:14          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

And I get this error in the SQL Server Kubernetes deployment:
2024-08-13 09:44:20.03 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2024-08-13 09:44:20.03 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'platformsdb'. [CLIENT: 10.1.1.203]

The connection string is:
   "PlatformsConn": "Server=mssql-clusterip-srv,1433;Initial Catalog=platformsdb;User Id=sa;Password=Pa55w0rd!;TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=False;"
So the server is the :ClusterIP of the SQL Server.
Here is the secret used:
kubectl create secret generic mssql --from-literal=MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD="Pa55w0rd!"

And I have a yaml file for the persistent volume:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi

And here is the deployment file of SQL Server, it contains also the clusterip that I am using in the connection string, and it contains loadbalance:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
            - name: MSSQL_PID
              value: "Express"
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
            - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mssql
                  key: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/
              name: mssqldb
      volumes:
        - name: mssqldb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mssql-claim1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - name: mssql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433

I have tried to connect to the SSMS using the: localhost,1433 with SA and PAssword, I was able to connect normally. Plus the SQL Server and Windows authentication turned on. I also tried to turn of the SQL instance.

@DaleK i added the text at the bottom

Well, it seems the issue is with that database, does it even exist?

@siggemannen  i have another appsetting.developement file, i tried to connect to localhost and ran migration to create it, so it exists ., but the connection string above it is in the appsettings.production

you say you connect by ssms using localhost, but isn't kubernetes sql server somewhere else? sounds like you're confusing your servers but i could be wrong. Also, if some migration creates the database, the connection string cannot point to that database, since it cannot create it. The whole thing is confusing for me
